# Trending venues endpoint not working

Tags: foursquare

This is more like a bug report than a question. I observed that the trending venues endpoint is returning this error:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 400,
        errorType: "param_error",
        errorDetail: "Value trending is invalid for venue id",
        requestId: "56869f2c498ebe6aa0f8428d"
    },
    notifications: [{
        type: "notificationTray",
        item: {
             unreadCount: 1
        }
    }],
    response: { }
}
```

It seems like the keyword *trending* is being treated like an ID. You can easily verify this using the [API Explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/trending%3Fll%3D40.7,-74).

Is there someone else experiencing this behavior or I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: same error for trending. i think there is a bug. cause it was working without any chage in  code. please let us know for any sollution

Comment: It seems that the bug is fixed. The trending endpoint is working now,

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be working now!  Likely a minor bug that was fixed.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues%2Ftrending%3Fll%3D40.7%2C-74